# Why am I getting black splotches in my Eevee render?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I'm currently using Eevee in Blender 3.6.  There's weird black bands that are happening in my renders, but not in render view.  I've tried changing every variable I can find in:

- Volumetrics
- Shadows
- Indirect Lighting
- Subsurface Scattering
- And every other tab that seemed related to shadows or light

The only thing I can think of that's strange about my setup is that it's very, very big.  Kilometers wide.

Link to file:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JFtX_77d0vf2_7e_8m7dX6yPpY5XxPGN/view?usp=sharing

Render:
[image]

Viewport Shading - Rendered:
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? Make it as simple as possible...

Comment: Could be a modifier issue, are they all turned on the same for render as viewport?

Comment: @moonboots I added a link to the file.  Blend-exchange doesn't work for me, so it's gdrive.

Comment: @3pointedit Great thinking!  I checked and that's not the issue, but it's a really good suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some objects that are disabled for preview but enabled for render, one of them overlaps with the visible object, disable them for render:

[image]